# OSB - Split-Join calling secured web service

Tags: parallel-processing, soa, osb

I create a new Split-Join (in the OSB workshop application). Then
I use an action "Invoke Service" to call a not secured business service. So far no problem. When I assign a security policy to my business service, the OSB does not accept. Here is the error message in the OSB workshop:
[Parallel, Scope, Invoke Service]
The WSDL Binding for BusinessService "OSB/1_0/BusinessServices/TestBS" is not supported: The service feature "WS-Security" is not supported.
How can I call a secured business service in a splitJoin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can never a call a WSDL based proxy/Business Service that has WS_POLICY defined in the WSDL. You need to have a intermediate business/proxy to pass the message to the WS-policy containg WSDL service.

Answer (score 1):

I'll put a little more expanded version of the correct answer of user2364825.

Split-Join is actually a "window" into an older product (that's why it looks and behave differently from OSB). That product has some limitation, including inability to work with WS_POLICY.

There are two commonly used workarounds for that.

Approach #1. Make a version of the same WSDL stripped of WS_POLICY and use it in the Split-Join. From the Split-Join, call the intermediate proxy with that stripped WSDL which in turn calls a business service with the original WSDL.

```
BizService(Stripped WSDL)->Split-Join->Proxy2(Stripped WSDL)->BizService(Real WSDL)
```

That approach only works if the WS_POLICY headers are created by OSB code.

If the message going via Split-Join already has some SOAP Headers (including Policies), those are going to be lost, and the approach #1 is not working.

Approach #2. Make a custom WSDL which wraps the original message with all its SOAP Headers and whatnot. Use that WSDL for Split-Join, pass the wrapped message to an unwrapping proxy, and then call the real proxy/biz.

```
BizService(Wrapper WSDL)->Split-Join->Proxy2(Wrapper WSDL)->BizService(Real WSDL)
```

The second approach is more complex, but also more powerful. For instance, it easily can be extended to support user headers (Split-Join doesn't support them too), passing debug information and pretty much anything else.

This approach is implemented in my [GenericParallel](http://genericparallel.com/quick-start) service which does all above and some more.

I also have a blog post outlining [passing the SOAP Headers via Split-Join](http://genericparallel.com/2014/05/passing-soapheader-via-split-join/) in a bit more details. (The WS_Policy is just a SOAP Header after all).